# How to divide a website into three unequal length columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have been trying to create a website divided into 3 Columns of unequal length, being more specific two of 15% in the sides, and one of 70% in the centre. However I am not being able to manage that the 3 columns take 100% width of the space of my wesbite.
Here's my code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.content {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

div.column1 {
  width: 15%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div.column2 {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
}

navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.navbar-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body style="padding-top: 70px">
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="img/logo.png" width="80" height="50" alt="" />
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">2</span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Classes</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="column1">
      <h1> this is column 1</h1>
      tting, remairem</div>

    <div class="column2">
      <h1> this is column 2</h1>
      Lorem Ip Lorem</div>

    <div class="column1">
      <h1> this is column 1</h1>
      Lorem Ipsum ing Lorem</div>
  </div>
```

As you can see I have on top of my body a fixed navbar that was imported from bootstrap from dreamweaver,
and the a new div containing the three columns.

With this code I get the following output:

[image]

Do you guys know why the columns are not taking 100% width of the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width of 100% wont work here, because parent of `div.content` is page body. Width of any % works, if the parent has already some width set, so the CSS has some value to calculate the % of. In this case, since you want it to cover the whole page, and the div does not have a parent, the easiest thing to do is to change `%` to `vw`.
`vw` stands for viewport-width and represents % of the whole page width (not parent).

```
div.content{
    width:100vw;
    display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely as helpful as code with explanation as to *why* or *how* a change it code works.

Comment: yeah I dont know why width viewport worked.